# Strict Standards trouble using arrays and end() function

Tags: php, arrays, function, breadcrumbs

Normally this function returns a breadcrumb like this:

> Home » Php » Test

But I want it to only display this:

> » Test

So I added this line: `return end(explode('Php',$str));`.
But now it returns this error and I don't know what to do with it.

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /php/functions.php on line 112

line 112 is the last line before the function ends.
Could you guys please help me out I'm stuck at this error with my project.

**Here is my code:**

```
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
// This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
$path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

// This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
$base = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

// Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
$breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");

// Find out the index for the last value in our path array
$pathkeys = array_keys($path); $last = end($pathkeys);

// Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
    // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
    $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

    // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
    if ($x != $last)
        $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb\">$title</a>";
    // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
    else
        $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
}

// Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string
$str = implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
//remove everything before "Php" in the string
return end(explode('Php',$str));
}
```

Comment: You can not  send explode to function end which moves array pointer. Save result of explode to a var and set it to end

Comment: thnx got it working now :D